# Which following sentences are correct? Who else or Who also

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, american-english, british-english

Who also sent documents by post?

**or**

Who else sent documents by post?

Comment: Which one do you think is correct? Why?

Answer (score 1):

> 1: *Who **also** sent documents by post?*

...isn't a particularly *likely* utterance, but it would [almost] always be interpreted as requesting a list of people who *posted* their documents ***as well as*** doing something else (filling in the same information to an online survey, for example).

> 2: *Who **else** sent documents by post?*

...would [definitely] always be interpreted as requesting a list of ***some additional people*** who *posted* documents - in a context where some people have already been identified as having posted their documents, and the speaker wants to know about any ***other*** people who did the same.

---

So far as I'm aware, ***else*** and ***also*** are not "cognate" (they don't have the same etymology), despite both being Germanic (having their origins in Old Frisian). But that's a level of detail too obscure for me.